# Hive connection to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two instances of Hadoop running. I have no control over the first instance. I setup the second instance.

I also installed Hive in this machine. When I try to create a table using hive, hive is trying to connect to first instance of Hadoop and try to write data using this instance.

I want to change the default Hadoop port that Hive is looking for so that Hive uses the second instance of Hadoop to write data. I have set the HADOOP_HOME, path, etc. correctly in the .basrc and sourced it.

Is there a way to change the default Hadoop's port that hive is looking for to write the data?

Comment: You installed both Hadoop instances on the same machine?

Comment: yes. Additional info: two instances are working fine and I can integrate with other tools, keeping data separate, etc. The only thing is that I haven't figured out a way for hive to connect to the Hadoop instance that I created

Comment: What do you mean you have two instances of Hadoop? Hadoop is a cluster technology, so are you running two independent NameNodes, DataNodes, YARN, etc? Have you researched ViewFS or federated Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop instance information for Hive are specified in `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`

Edit it manually if you deployed standalone Hadoop, with Ambari/Cloudera Manager if you used HDP/CDH, and then restart Hive service so it reloads the configuration and you should be good

Comment: I had gone through this conf file earlier, I think it's hive-default.xml with my version of Hive, but could not find a reference, where I could change a URL to point to my Hadoop instance. Could you please throw some light? Also, I installed Hive using a tar ball and initialized metadata to a MySQL database

Comment: @kumaran `hive-default.xml` is overwritten with a customized `hive-site.xml`, which must be created. It is not version specific.

Comment: thanks. I changed it to hive-site.xml and restarted. It still references my first instances of Hadoop. Can someone please point me to which property to change to point to a specific instance of Hadoop?

Comment: @kumaran see @cricket_007 answer, it's `fs.defaultFS`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the default Hadoop's port that hive is looking for to write the data?

If I understand correct, you want to change the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml` file to modify the `fs.defaultFS` address to a different HDFS NameNode.